# scrapy xpath return empty data from table

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i try get href from this table

```
<div class="squad-container">
  <table class="table squad sortable" id="page_team_1_block_team_squad_8-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="group-head">
        <th colspan="4">Goalkeepers </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:50px;"><a href="/474798/" style="display:block;width:50px; height:50px;">Reda Sayed</a></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
          <div><a href="/474798/" >Reda Sayed</a></div>
          <div style="padding-left: 27px;">25 years old</div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

i use

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="table squad sortable"]//tr//td//a/@href').extract_first()
```

and didnt work with i need know what is the problem in code and what is different if i use double // or single slash

Comment: the xpath seems correct and `//` is ignoring anything in between

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem with your xpath from we human's perspective. However, the xpath or css can be different from your spider's perspective, i.e. your spider may 'see' page differently.

Try using 'scrapy shell' to test your xpath or css and see if any data can be extracted. Here is the link to the doc in case you need: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

To sum up: modify the xpath you wrote, 'cause your spider won't find any data with that xpath, and scrapy shell can help you.:)